# Commands for correct deploy

Tags: magento2, magento-1.9, deploy, command

What are the basic commands to be executed for Deploy in Magento 1 and Magento 2 after doing the git pull?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magento DevDocs is providing a basic list of command [Magento2 DevDocs](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands.html)

Comment: Does the same for Magento 1 exist?

Comment: I am not sure about Magento 1